# написать функцию,которая меняет прозрачность до нуля у блока(div),при клике

Tags: javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
<style>
.block
{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: red;
    opacity: 1;

}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="block" ></div>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

я предлагаю просто сделать find element class "block" и добавить ему другой класс у которого 
opacity:0 !important;

```
var btns = document.getElementsByClassName('block');
var par = document.getElementsByClassName('someclass'); // на какой класс кликать
btns[0].onclick = function() {
  par[0].classList.add("opacyti ");
}
```

css

```
.opacyti {
  opacity:0 !important;
}
```

Comment: Павел,у моего задания,есть продолжение

Comment: 2*. При клике по блоку он начинает плавно исчезать. После того, как он исчез - опять плавно появляется
3*. блок ходит по периметру top++, top ---

Comment: jquery подключен?
блок ходит по периметру top++, top ---   где эти блоки или это высота? Тогда какая?

Comment: нет,чистый js..

Comment: const block =document.querySelector('.block');
  block.addEventListener('click', moveblock);
  let x = 0;

  function moveblock(){
   let mIter = setInterval(function(){
    x+=2;
    block.style.left = x + 'px';
    if(x>=500){
     clearInterval(mIter);
    }
   }, 10);
   
  }

Comment: это функция при которой блок двигается по x

Comment: высота,ширина блока в стиле,прописана,эти действия должны происходить с этим блоком